# Can the integral comparison test be used if the upper limit is finite?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I came across a task where it is required to determine whether or not the following integral converges.

> $$\iint_{x^2+y^2 \le 1} \dfrac{dxdy}{(x^2 + xy + y^2)^p}$$

Converting to polar coordinates, we have

$$ \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi}\int_{r = 0}^{1} \dfrac{drd\theta}{r^{2p-1} (\sin\theta \cos\theta)^p} = \dfrac1{2-2p} \int_{0}^{2\pi} (\sin\theta \cos\theta)^{-p } d\theta = \dfrac1{2-2p} \int_{ 0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{(\sin\theta \cos\theta)^p } d\theta $$

I'm not quite sure how to deal with the last integral. I have tried using Euler's formula to replace $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ with their equivalent exponential-complex forms but unfortunately, the imaginary component does not vanish in the result:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \left ( \dfrac{4i}{e^{2i\theta}- e^{-2i\theta}} \right) ^p d\theta$$

Therefore, I tried to use the comparison test. For $p>0$, where $p$ is even

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{(\sin\theta \cos\theta)^p } d\theta \leq \int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{|(\sin\theta \cos\theta)|^p } d\theta \leq \int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{\theta^p } d\theta$$

Thus

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{\theta^p } d\theta = \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{1}{\theta^p } d\theta + \int_{1}^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{\theta^p } d\theta$$

Since the assumption was that $p$ is even and $p>0$, the last result diverges.

I am not very confident in this solution since we usually apply the comparison test when the integrals are improper i.e have infinite limits. Therefore, any clarification on this is highly appreciated.

**Edit**:
As pointed out in the comment section, I forgot to add $1$ in the denominator.

Comment: $x^2+xy+y^2=r^2(\color{red}{1}+\sin\theta\cos\theta)$

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral will diverge for $r\in (0,1)$ if $p \ge 1$, so let us make this interval as $(a,1)$ $$I(p)= \int_{a}^{1} \frac{dr}{r^{2p-1}}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{\left(1+\frac{\sin 2\theta}{2}\right)^p}=\frac{1-a^{2-2p}}{2(1-p)} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{\left(1+\frac{\sin 2\theta}{2}\right)^p}$$
$$\implies I(p)=\frac{1-a^{2-2p}}{1-p} J(p) \implies I(1)=\lim_{p \rightarrow 1} I(p)=-2 \ln a ~J(1)$$
These $J(p)$ integrals can befound interms of Gauss hypergeometric functions
in Mathematica. They may also be done analytically some values of $p$.
For instance for $p=1$, we get
$$J(1)=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{\left(1+\frac{\sin2\theta}{2}\right)}=\int_{0}^{\pi} d\theta \left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{\sin 2\theta}{2}}+ \frac{1}{1-\frac{\sin 2\theta}{2}} \right) =\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{8 d\theta}{4-\sin^2 2\theta}$$
$$\implies J(1)= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{4du}{4-\sin^2u}=\frac{16}{3} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{sec^2 u ~ du}{\tan^2u+4/3}=\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: I am unclear how you determined that the integral will diverge for $p \geq 1 , r \in (0,1)$. Also, in the second line, isn't $I(1)=\lim_{p \rightarrow 1} = 0$ since, by L'hopital's rule $$ \lim_{p \rightarrow 1} \frac{1-a^{2-2p}}{1-p} = \dfrac00 \implies \lim_{p \rightarrow 1} \frac{1-a^{2-2p}}{1-p} = \lim_{p \rightarrow 1} \frac{-(2-2p)a^{1-2p}}{-1} =  \lim_{p \rightarrow 1} (2-2p)a^{1-2p} = 0$$

Comment: Sorry, your third term is not correct it should be $\lim_{p \rightarrow 1} -a^{2-2p}~ 2~ \ln a=-2 \ln a$, it is differentiation w.r.t. $p$ (not w.r.x. $a$) Also $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x^b} $ is finite if $b<1$, other wise it is divergent. So by introducing the interval of $r\in(a,1)$ we can stop this divergence for any real value of $p$.

Comment: Oh, I see where I went wrong.

Comment: I sat down and tried to write a proper solution and realised I'm still missing a few things. When showing divergence,  doesn't $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{r^{2p-2}} $ imply divergence for $p\geq \frac32$?